# Get current package name on initialization

Tags: delphi, initialization, package

My application dynamically load packages that provide implementation of objects I need. I've got a global function to register object classes on a list structure which I use to create instances dynamically.

```
procedure RegisterObjectStd(const APackageName, AObjectName: string; const AClass: TClass);
```

Thereby I can create an instance referenced to a particular context through a factory method

Example:

```
function CreateObject(const APackageName, AObjectName: string): TObject;
```

Is there a way to dinamically retrieve the name of the current package (.bpl) in my initialization code?

```
initialization
  RegisterObjectStd(GetCurrentBplName, 'MyObjectName', TMyObjectClass);
```

Comment: What about `GetModuleName(HInstance)`?

Comment: That gets the file name which may not be equal to the package name, potentially. A good example are versioned packages. For instance, the package named `rtl` might have a filename like `rtl210.bpl`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it using `GetPackageInfo` from `System.SysUtils`. It's a little involved to call, so here I demonstrate how to wrap it up to obtain the package name:

```
procedure GetPackageNameInfoProc(const Name: string; NameType: TNameType; Flags: Byte; 
  Param: Pointer);
begin
  if NameType=ntDcpBpiName then begin
    PString(Param)^ := Name;
  end;
end;

function GetPackageName(Package: HMODULE): string;
var
  Flags: Integer;
begin
  // Flags should be an out param, but is a var, so this assignment is a little pointless
  Flags := 0; 
  Result := '';
  GetPackageInfo(Package, @Result, Flags, GetPackageNameInfoProc);
end;
```

You can use this on any runtime package loaded in your process. If you want to call it on the package that the code is execiting in, pass `HInstance` to `GetPackageName`.